# Why does this not sort the list?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was able to fix it by actually creating a new ArrayList, with each element being a char array, by I would've thought I had the reference of each elements char array, and by sorting it and adding it to a new list, that each element would be a sorted char array. Just to improve my conceptual understanding, please shed some light. Thanks

Suppose I have a a list of words, = "Stack", "Mack", in an ArrayList named words, I want to sort each element of words alphabetically, i.e element 0 of sortedWords should be ackSt, etc. I know how to do this, but I was surprised as to how I couldn't do it by pointing to it.

```
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groupedAnagrams = new ArrayList<>();
              ArrayList<char[]> sortedWords = new ArrayList<>();
              for(String word : words){
                  //char[] sortedWord = word.toCharArray();
                  Arrays.sort(word.toCharArray());
                  sortedWords.add(word.toCharArray());
              }
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(word.toCharArray());` manipulate the `char[]`, basically changing the word (not the String object, the word stored in your `char[]`). I am not sure I am following what are you after.

Comment: Your commented out code seems to be the right approach: get the char[] from the string. Then, sort it. Then, add that to your sortedWords[]. Otherwise, the word.toCharArray() is creating an array that you sort. Then, you're ignoring it and creating a brand new charArray()from your string.

Comment: Is the confusion coming from the fact that `toCharArray` isn't returning a reference to some already existing object?

Comment: @DariusX. Thank you; I was just confused with how the reference would work. That makes sense. I thought by invoking sort on the word's char array, the word's char array would then be sorted for eternity.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Yes. That bothered me for a moment. I felt like by having a new char array point to the words char array, I was doing additional, inefficient work.

Comment: String is a special Object, mostly in that it's immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the array that gets sorted in the line

```
Arrays.sort(word.toCharArray());
```

disappears. The reference isn't saved, so when you call

```
sortedWords.add(word.toCharArray());
```

this is a new array. You need:

```
char[] sortedWord = word.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(sortedWord);
sortedWords.add(sortedWord);
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort` is a void method, you cannot assign back the result of the sort to a char array.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at source code of [String#toCharArray()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.toCharArray%28%29):

```
/**
 * Converts this string to a new character array.
 *
 * @return  a newly allocated character array whose length is the length
 *          of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain
 *          the character sequence represented by this string.
 */
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count];
    getChars(0, count, result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Every time it returns you a new `char[]`.

You haven't stored the returned array hence the sorting result has been lost after sorting.